# Не получается выбрать связаные друг с другом записи из двух таблиц

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, база-данных

Организовываю поиск по пользователям используя фильтр для подбора по параметрам.
У меня есть две таблицы :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой пример запроса :

```
SELECT  u.uid, u.name, u.surname, e.*
  FROM  users u, education e
  WHERE u.uid = e.uid
  OR e.startYear = 2012
  OR e.overYear = 2016
  OR u.name LIKE '%Андрей%'
  OR u.surname LIKE '%Андрей%' 
  OR e.name LIKE '%АБВГД%'
```

Значении которые встречаются в БД это `e.startYear = 2012` и `e.overYear = 2016`, пользователь с именем или фамилией `Андрей` или `e.name` с значением `АБВГД` нету.
В таблице education есть всего лишь две строки.
Запрос выводит список всех пользователей и данные таблицы education.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как мне получать список всех пользователей используя этот фильтр ?

Comment: А еще почему-то `u.uid = e.uid` не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам незачем добавлять ненужные условия на столбцы, вроде `OR u.name LIKE '%Андрей%'` - их можно просто стереть.

Сейчас ваш запрос делает следующее: берёт все строки из таблицы `users`, к каждой строке добавляет все строки из таблицы `education` (например, если в первой было 5 записей, во второй 10, в запросе пока получится 50). После этого оставляются только те строки, которые удовлетворяют запросу, т.е. у которых:

1. `u.uid = e.uid`
2. *Или* `e.startYear = 2012`
3. *Или* `e.overYear = 2016`

Например, из-за условия 1 выведена строка 2, а из-за условий 2 и 3 выведены все остальные.

У вас два варианта действий. Первый - поправить запрос так, чтобы он действительно делал то, что надо: чтобы *одновременно* выполнялось `u.uid = e.uid` и условие на год обучения. Для этого можно использовать логический оператор `AND` и скобки:

```
SELECT  u.uid, u.name, u.surname, e.*
  FROM  users u, education e
  WHERE (u.uid = e.uid)
    AND (e.startYear = 2012 OR e.overYear = 2016)
```

Второй - использовать общепринятую в современном мире команду `JOIN` (запросы через несколько таблиц в `FROM` считаются устаревшими), заодно это будет более эффективно по времени на больших объёмах данных. Не знаю, что за БД вы используете, но будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.surname, e.*
  FROM users u
  JOIN education e ON u.uid = e.uid
  WHERE e.startYear = 2012
     OR e.overYear = 2016
```

Comment: Второй запрос мне понравился. А если мне еще нужно отфильтровать по имени и фамилии? что еще нужно добавить в запрос? @yeputons

Comment: Просто добавляете дополнительные условия к `WHERE` как обычно, формируя произвольные условия на строчки из результата, вроде `(e.startYear = 2012 OR e.overYear = 2016) AND e.name = 'Андрей'` - найдёт Андреев, который либо начали в 2012, либо закончили в 2016.

Comment: P.S. Если считаете, что ответ полностью решает вашу проблему, вы можете [его принять](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)